# Circle is not rendering on google map with React Google Map's API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to render a google circle with React's google maps api, but it doesn't show up. We didn't get any error messages. We don't understand why we cannot render the circle after following the instructions even though we have set the circle's defaultCenter and radius.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import bunnyHere from "../../../images/here.png";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker} from "google-maps-react";
import Circle from "google-maps-react";
import BackButton from "../../../components/Buttons/BackButton/BackButton";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

class FindHospitalPage extends Component {
  state = {
    markers: [
      { lat: 35.700688, lng: 139.772478 },
      { lat: 35.713521, lng: 139.799845 }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "flex-end",
            marginRight: "15px"
          }}
        >
          <NavLink to="/homepage">
            <Button>Back To Homepage</Button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={15}
            style={mapStyles}
            initialCenter={{ lat: 35.707719, lng: 139.774846 }}
          >
            {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) => (
              <Marker key={i} position={marker} />
            ))}
            <Marker
              position={{ lat: 35.707719, lng: 139.774846 }}
              icon={bunnyHere}
              animation={this.props.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE}
            />
            <Circle
                defaultCenter={{ lat: 35.707719, lng: 139.774846 }}
                defaultRadius={500}
                options={{
                  strokeColor: '#0022ff',
                  fillColor: '#0099ff',
                  fillOpacity: 0.1
                }}
            />
          </Map>
        </div>
        <BackButton buttonType={"buttonType_2"} backPage={"/checkout"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// export default FindHospitalPage;
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "XXX"
})(FindHospitalPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting this warning in console

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

It appears the support for `Circle` component was introduced in version `2.0.3` **but** the *latest* version of `google-maps-react` [available from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) is `2.0.2`,  probably it is better to contact library author(s) why `2.0.3` still not available from npm.

Meanwhile (`2.0.3`) version could be installed from GitHub like this:

```
npm install https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react.git
```

Once installed, the following example demonstrates how to render map along with a circle

```
class MapExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        className={"map"}
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={5}
        initialCenter={{ lat: -24.6651078, lng: 126.4247918 }}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat: -24.6651078, lng: 126.4247918 }}
          animation={this.props.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE}
        />
        <Circle center={{ lat: -24.6651078, lng: 126.4247918 }} radius={500000} />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "--your key goes here--"
})(MapExample);
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Vadim. I will make an issue and contact the library author(s).